# Reactjs: CJSX Nested Conditionals

Tags: reactjs

What is the correct syntax to handle nested conditional logic in a React component?

```
React.createClass
render: ->
  <div>
    {if @props.showList
      {for item in @props.myItems
        {item}
      }
    else
    }
  </div>
```

The for loop (on its own) can be rendred; the if/else conditional (on its own) can be rendered. However, nesting the for loop inside the conditional fails.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested it, but based on how normal JSX works you only need the `{expression}` thing to escape from JSX mode.

The program starts in JS mode (or CS here), and when an element tag is encountered it enters JSX mode.  Using `{foo}` in JSX mode causes it to go back to JS mode.  From there the above rules apply, and you can re-enter JSX mode by starting a tag, and so on.

```
render: ->
  <div>
    {
    if @props.showList
      for item in @props.myItems
        item

    else
       <div>{foo}</div>
    }
  </div>
```

With annotations:

CoffeeScript:

```
render: ->
```

JSX within CoffeeScript

```
  <div>
```

CoffeeScript within JSX within CoffeeScript

```
    {
    if @props.showList
      for item in @props.myItems
        item

    else
```

JSX within CoffeeScript within JSX within CoffeeScript

```
       <div>
```

CoffeeScript within JSX within CoffeeScript

```
          {foo}
```

JSX within CoffeeScript

```
       </div>
```

JSX within CoffeeScript

```
    }
  </div>
```

CoffeeScript

```
...
```

Comment: I had resorted to breaking out each nested conditional to its own react class; and it did not feel right. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

Inside the `{}` sections you can just use normal Coffeescript/CJSX code, as long as it evaluates to a single expression:

```
React.createClass
  render: ->
    <div>
      {
        if @props.showList
          for item in @props.myItems
            <span key={item.id}>{item}</span>
        else
          <span>some other content</span>
      }
    </div>
```