# Reactjs map returns unexpected token }

Tags: javascript, dictionary, token, reactjs

I've been looking for this error, but haven't found it anywhere. I'm new to React and following some tutorials. Everything has worked up to the point where I'm trying to map an array to a component.

so I'm using dummy data to test this function in a smaller form

```
var data = [
    {name: 'You', text: 'Test'},
    {name: 'Me', text: 'Testing'}
];
```

Now I am trying to print out a comment system, and for now I'm only trying to print out the names of the users.
I'm giving my application component the data, which gives it to the messagelist. There I'm trying to print them into boxes.

```
var MessageList = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var messages = this.props.data.map(function(msg) { 
            return <MessageBox name={msg.name} />
        });    //**** ERROR HERE ****
        return {messages};
    }
});
```

I indicated the line where the error occurs.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

I don't think I need to add any additional info as all other features were working fine, this is the only thing that returns an error.
Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `messages` is an array and your component should return one single element, you should wrap it with another component:

```
return (<div>{messages}</div>);
```

Comment: Also see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26876829/1074592).  You only need the `{expression}` to escape a JSX context.  e.g. `return foo` vs `return <div>{foo}</div>`.